# How node module include in Core angular project

Tags: angularjs, npm

I am working in angular 1.5 and I need to integrate a module in my project.

My project is in core angular and module is in `npm`, so I need to add that module in my project.

How can I do that?

Comment: Just add a script tag in your index.html referencing all the js files you need, it doesn't matter where they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use it in your project with

```
npm install <package_name>
```

or if you're using bower you can also do it like

```
bower install <package_name>
```

Comment: but it will return lots files bunch after that what should i need to do ?

Comment: It will only install the mentioned package, so only the files related to that particular package will be loaded .. So you don't have to take worry about it ..